# navigate from nested TapNavigator to parent (stacknavigator) details screen

Tags: react-native, navigation

I am new to react native. I am using [react-navigation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation) npm for route navigation.Could not navigate from nested tap navigator to parent stack navigator's screen.I used `onPress={() => navigate('Details')}` method in IndividualChat screen and then I referred [navigate from nested StackNavigator to parent's router screen](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/335) issue and [react navigation actions](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-actions) I didn't get clearly.

**Sample Code:**

```
    const ChatScreen = TabNavigator({
        Message: { screen: IndividualChat },
        Group: { screen: GroupChat }
    });

    const HomeScreen = StackNavigator({
       Home: {
          screen: Login,
       },
       Profile: {
          screen: ChatScreen
      },
      Details: {
          screen: DetailsScreen
      }
    });
```

**snippet**

https://snack.expo.io/By1ZzDyXz

**What I need**

I need to navigate from IndividualChat screen to details screen.

Comment: I know it has been a long time but have you found a solution?

Answer (score 3):

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';


const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
          index: 0,
          key:null,
          actions: [
            NavigationActions.navigate({
              routeName: 'Details'
            })
          ]
        })
      );

this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

The key here is use the 'StackActions' and set 'key:null' that if set to nullwill reset the root navigator.

[StackActions reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html#reset)