# How to navigate to another screen in a nested navigator in React-Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I just implemented bottom navigation bar and it seems like I need to change the way I navigate between screens now on. This is how I was doing it before:

```
onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('my_profile')}
```

but now it doesn't work, it shows this message:

> **Do you have a screen named 'my_profile'?
> If you're trying to navigate to a screen in a nested navigator, see https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigato**

This is how I have implemented the bottom tab:

```
export default function home_customers() {    
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={home_customer_screen} />
            <Tab.Screen name="More" component={settings_screen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

//this class below is located in the same file with the function home_customers
class home_customer_screen extends Component{ 
   ... 
}

//this class is located in a different file that's why I am exporting it
export default class settings_screen extends Component{ 
   render() {
    return (
        <View>                    
             <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('my_profile')}>                           
               <Text>My profile/Text>                           
             </TouchableOpacity>                             
        </View >
    );
  } 
}

//this is where I am trying to navigate to
export default class my_profile extends Component {
 ...
}
```

**FYI: I am not using Functions but Classes!**

**UPDATE**

I am using nested navigators. This is the `createStackNavigator` located in another file:

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
     login: {
        screen: login
     },
     home_customers: {
        screen: home_customers
     },
     settings_screen: {
        screen: settings_screen       
     },
     my_profile: {
        screen: my_profile        
     },
   },
     {
        initialRouteName: "login"
     }
);
```

Comment: In the snippet you posted, there is indeed no screen named `my_profile`. The only two are `Home` and `More`.

Comment: @YanickBélanger I updated my question, I am actually trying to navigate to that screen. `More` and `Home` are the screens that I can navigate to using Bottom Tab. When I go to `More` screen I have a button which onClick should send me to `my_profile` screen.

Comment: Does this solve your issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976460/navigate-from-nested-tapnavigator-to-parent-stacknavigator-details-screen?

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I don't understand the `dispatch`, cant I just use the `navigation.navigate`? I think the only thing I am missing is passing the navigation as a parameter to the class but don't know-how. I can see many examples using Functions but not Classes

Comment: Well the problem is that you're not going from parent to child, but from child to parent. If it was the other way around we could use `navigation.navigate` like described here https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#navigating-to-a-screen-in-a-nested-navigator. All the navigation functions like `navigate` use dispatch in the background https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch. The reason the answer uses dispatch is because it can be combined with StackActions in a way where the navigation state gets reset and you can navigate to a screen from the top level.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden I tried like that but it cannot find `navigation` , this is the error reference: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: navigation`

Comment: After making sure you're using consistent syntax like `YanickBélanger` mentioned there is also another approach if you're using version 5 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62941680/how-to-navigate-from-a-functional-component-from-a-screen-in-a-tab-navigator-w/62944296#62944296. It's possible to navigate without access to the navigation prop. Then you can navigate from the top level to any screen by creating a ref and passing it to your `NavigationContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

From your updated snippet, you seem to be trying to use the react-navigation V4 syntax when defining your stack navigator  and the V5 syntax for the tab navigator.

I would suggest you read the stack navigation [guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation) in order to define your screens appropriately.

Once that is done you'll be able to navigate correctly.

Comment: I was about to mention this. If OP wants to go from child to parent he probably still need to do something like this though https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976460/navigate-from-nested-tapnavigator-to-parent-stacknavigator-details-screen. But rethinking the way the navigation hierarchy is set up OP can probably avoid the problem altogether. That is, making sure you don't need to navigate from child to parent in the first place.

Comment: I am using the latest version downloaded using npm, so why are you saying it seems like I am using version 4?

Comment: I said you're using the V4 syntax, instead of the V5 one. Notice how your stack and tab navigators are very different.